# Pick combinations from a list in python

Tags: python, list, combinations

Is there a way I can pick all n-combinations from a list

Suppose my list is `[1,2,3]` is there a way I can get the result as

```
[ [1] , [2] , [3] , [1,2] , [2,3] , [1,3] , [1,2,3] ]
```

p.s I don's want both `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` to be returned.

I'm sorry if the question is framed poorly

Comment: hi this has already been asked and answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/4508178

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)